# laravel/php, take selected ID from sql pdo and use it as variable in future call

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a Laravel function where I'm running a fairly simple SQL query on db2, I'm selecting the newly created record's id upon an insert, like so:

```
$sql = " select imaget_id from NEW TABLE (
INSERT INTO IMAGE (name, description, url, image_typet_id)
VALUES (:commonName, :type, :imageZoneName,
        (select image_typet_id from image_typet where name = :imageZoneDescription))
); " 

$pdoStatement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($imageZoneNames as $images) {
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':commonName',           $commonName            );
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':type',                 $type                  );
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':imageZoneName',        $images['name']);
        $pdoStatement->bindParam(':imageZoneDescription', $images['desc']);

        $pdoStatement->execute();

        //I'll need the Image ID here
    }
```

The insert itself works without any issue at all, but I need to take that selected ID and use it after my execute to use as a parameter for another call. SO if my insert returns id `123` I'll need that as a variable like `$newId`

How can I properly take this newly generated and selected ID and use it as its own variable after the execute statement?

Comment: Can you go with `$pdo->lastInsertId()` ? [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: @user3647971 I haven't actually tried, let me see if that works here. If so, can I store that into it's own variable as well?

Comment: Yeah, umm not sure if you should use reference `$id = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();` or `$pdoStatement->lastInsertId();`

Comment: @user3647971 I see. I was able to plug it in as the PDO function but my db2 driver doesn't support it, unfortunately

Comment: are you running this as a transaction? if so could you try the following within the same transaction ```SELECT SYSIBM.IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() AS id FROM schema.table``` obviously swapping schema and table for your values.

Comment: If that query returns a row you can just fetch it with `$result = $pdoStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. Id will be in `$result['imaget_id'];`

Comment: More information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: If you use Eloquent models, on the other hand, the `id` becomes available immediately after `$model->save()`, and you could access it using `$model->id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved very easily using `Eloquent`. 
You'll need two models:

```
php artisan make:model Image
php artisan make:model ImageTypet
```

More on configuring your models [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#defining-models).

Import your models in the controller:

```
use App\Image;
use App\ImageTypet;
```

In your controller method:

```
foreach ($imageZoneNames as $images) {
    $typetId = ImageTypet::where('name', $images['desc'])->value('image_typet_id');

    $imageModel = new Image;
    
    $imageModel->name            = $commonName;
    $imageModel->description     = $type;
    $imageModel->url             = $images['name'];
    $imageModel->image_typet_id  = $typetId;

    $imageModel->save()

    $imageId = $imageModel->id //Here's your ID, immediately available after save().
}
```